# Why does this SoundCloud API method not retrieve all tracks?

Tags: soundcloud

I'm attempting to retrieve all of [my favourited songs](https://soundcloud.com/goodforenergy/likes) from my profile on SoundCloud using the [SoundCloud API method](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users) `/users/{id}/favorites`.

After registering my application with SoundCloud and retrieving my ClientID, I can successfully retrieve an array of favourited tracks in JSON using a call to `http://api.soundcloud.com/users/goodforenergy/favorites?client_id={my-client-id}`.

Looking at my SoundCloud profile, however, you can see I have (at this moment in time) 182 likes - but the method is only returning 48.

Any ideas as to why? I thought there may be a `next_href` returned in the JSON that I was expected to follow to retrieve more, but I don't see any. In any case, 48 seems a very arbitrary number to return!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [soundcloud api docs](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#search) most of the results in the API are returned in collections which are limited by default to a size of 50. I realize that it's peculiar that you are seeing 48 rather than 50 but it's probably worth modifying your call to support pagination.

> Most endpoints support a linked_partitioning parameter that will allow you to page through collections. When this parameter is passed, the response will contain a next_href property if there are additional results.

So you need to update your API call to include the `linked_partitioning` and `limit` parameters in order to recieve a `next_href`.

Comment: Changing the URL to include `limit=50&linked_partitioning=1` resulted still only in returning 48 results, but also provided the missing `next_href` link that lets me access more. Increasing the limit to 200 meant I got 168 of my 182 favourites returned. Strange, but perhaps some are filtered out because of their uploader's settings. 

Anyhow, thanks! :)